# Placing an image inside a Span programmatically

Tags: asp.net, html

Placing an **image** inside a **Span** (here : `HtmlGenericControl` ) programmatically
Want to have a process on it later via the `FindControl`

```
        HtmlGenericControl spnMeta = new HtmlGenericControl("span") 
            { ID = "spanMeta" };
        //Literal litMeta = new Literal();
        //litEdit.Text = "<span id=\"spanMeta\" class=\"meta\" runat=\"server\">" ;

        Image imgCodeIcon = new Image()
        {
            ID="imgCodeIcon" ,
            ImageUrl="../Images/Code-icon.gif" ,
            Width = 15 , Height = 11 
        };
        spnMeta.Controls.Add(imgCodeIcon);
        // Shouldn't be important here ...
        spnMeta.DataBinding +=new EventHandler(spnMeta_DataBinding);

        // closing Span if Literal is used
```

Doing this way will have no effect :

```
spnMeta.Controls.Add(imgCodeIcon);
```

and image will be rendered outside of the span and next to it

Formerly I made the procedure via Literal as it's commented out in the below code block
but that time seemed I can not access to it from server code

**how could I achieve this ?**

Comment: It's not possible this way :         spnMeta.Controls.Add(imgCodeIcon);
How ?

Comment: do get an error? I did it and it works ok.

Comment: Ok I'll play with it, maybe the problem be for another part or a missed part, I'll probing it, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some sample code to place an image into a placeholder via code:

**ASPX**

```
<div>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ph1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
</div>
```

**C#**

```
        HtmlGenericControl spnMeta = new HtmlGenericControl("span") { ID = "spanMeta" };
        Image imgCodeIcon = new Image()
        {
            ID = "imgCodeIcon",
            ImageUrl = "../Images/Code-icon.gif",
            Width = 15,
            Height = 11
        };
        spnMeta.Controls.Add(imgCodeIcon);
        ph1.Controls.Add(spnMeta);
```

This is the output:

```
<div>
    <span id="spanMeta"><img id="imgCodeIcon" src="../Images/Code-icon.gif" style="height:11px;width:15px;" /></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure about the output you provided ? Does the span covered the image ?

Comment: The only difference is that I have a PlaceHolder control that I am adding the SPAN tag to.

Comment: I saw, Does it do the job ? I didn't test it yet, anyway thanks participating

Comment: No problem. Yes it works, see the output I have posted above.

Comment: I meant the Placeholder, Is the PlaceHolder made the code work correctly or it was working without it and the placeholder is an extra suggestion ?

Comment: If you do not use the PlaceHolder it will be added at the very end of the HTML page markup. If you use the PlaceHolder control then it will get added exactly where you want it. So use the PlaceHolder.